# VBA Worsheet_Calculate event triggers all the time

Tags: vba

In theory, the following VBA code should be triggered everytime any formula on the worksheet change, but I want the actual action to be triggered only if the value in A1 (A1 contains the RTD formula monitoring market data which is updated literally every second) is different from A3, so it should display the value of A1 only on occasions when values are different, but it displays the value very frequently (even if the values in A1 and A3 are the same). What is the problem?
Thanks.

```
private sub worksheet_calculate()
    If Range("A3").Value <> Range("A1").Value Then
        Range("A3").Value=Range("A1").Value
        Debug.Print Range("A1").Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't the statement "the following VBA code should be triggered everytime any formula on the worksheet changes" answer the "but it displays the value very frequently" question?

Comment: No because of If statement...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the values are really different at some decimal point you are not seeing. You could consider rounding the values, forcing the number of digits after decimal to a maximum significant value.

You could also consider using the "_change" event instead of "_calculate" as it gives you control over the target being changed. You need to test if the RTD forumla triggers the "_change" event though.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim RoundDigits As Integer
    RoundDigits = 6 'Change to how many digits you require rounding
   If Target.Address = Range("a1").Address Then
        If Round(Range("A3").Value, RoundDigits) <> Round(Range("A1").Value, RoundDigits) Then
            Range("A3").Value = Range("A1").Value
            Debug.Print Range("A1").Value
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does not work with formulas. That's why I inserted the code to copy the value from A1 to A3, so I can then work with Worksheet_Change statement and A3.

Answer (score 0):

Turned ou that for some reason values in A3 and A1 were different despite copying values. StrComp function solved the problem.